# Wordpress-Add variation boxes according to quanity

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to implement something like this :

I have a product shoes , with variation size and color, now if i add two products in cart, i need to have 4 variation drop-downs , if i add 3 shoes product i need 6 variation drop-downs , size and color for each product.

Like this 1) http://prntscr.com/chmn21 2)http://prntscr.com/chmng8

Let me know, if there is any plugin available or any way to do so.

Thanks

Comment: What did you examine yourself?

Comment: Also, what ecommerce plugin are you using? I think we'll need more information to help out.